# Wear OS 2.0 - Is there any way to process html, web page, programmatically?

Tags: android-webview, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I can't seem to find ANY information on Android Wear OS and html. My end goal is just to show a simple web page with buttons for IOT control. I have all the backend already. I know I can use other views but my backend dynamically creates a page of buttons. I'm open to other ideas for dynamically building an interface. I know webview isn't supported. I found crosswalk-project but it's no longer maintained and seem too complex for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeckoView might be a good starting point https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/geckoview-quick-start.html

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/geckoview_example

But it probably won't be a great experience.

Comment: I am actually using GeckoView. It was a bit difficult at first but I figured it out. Thanks! This is good enough for an answer though as it's the ONLY thing I could find to display webpages on Wear OS. It actually works quite well on my TicWatch!