# WearOS support for PWA

Tags: android, reactjs, api, progressive-web-apps, wear-os

I'm digging over internet on how to make a PWA app made with react.js run over WearOS, but I do not find any article. Also, the WearOS website is empty of information of this type, as well. Is the WearOS able to run a PWA app? What are the differences between a WearOS PWA app and a normal Android PWA app? If PWA can run on WearOS, all the APIs (GPS, Phone, camera, BT, wifi, etc.) are available to the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progressive Web Apps are NOT supported since the required WebKit APIs aren't available.

From: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/wear-v-mobile

> Feature: Connectivity
>
> For example, the `android.webkit` APIs aren't supported.

From: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/network-access

> **Network Access**
>
> You can use protocols such as HTTP, TCP, and UDP. However, the `android.webkit` APIs (including the `CookieManager` class) are not available. You can use cookies by reading and writing headers on requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could install Samsungs browser.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser&hl=en_GB&gl=US

But you probably won't have access to most of the APIs you are after.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551661/1542667

You could also embed a browser component like Gecko  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551661/1542667

But it's probably as much work as implementing a basic wear app, which will be easier for users.